# Chrome crawls on Linux whereas Firefox is light as a feather

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, memory, browser

In day to day browsing i find Chrome to consume x2 memory, has memory leaks with some sites (NYT, some ebay pages, with or without flash) whereas on Firefox is light as a feather. I'm a converted Chrome user after been in FF and now i have everything suited to work with Chrome, so is not so easy to me just to switch to FF back.

So i wonder if this kind of sluggishness is common in Chrome for Linux (Ubuntu 13.04 x64, gnome3, latest stable Chrome, to be exact) and if just have to deal with it or other users do not have this type of behaviours.

Comment: This is definitely [chrome](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/) and not [chromium](http://www.chromium.org/Home)?

Comment: Yes, Chrome stable. Version 29.0.1547.65

Comment: If you disable all addons, plugins, and userscripts, does the speed issue remains?

Comment: At first disregarded extensions as they were not showing significant naughty behavior in the Task Manager, however, after disabling all of them i noticed a massive improvement. I'll have to check one by one to find the resource-hungry one.

Comment: As a start, try disabling hardware rendering, and make sure it is using the inbuilt flash plugin in chrome://plugins

Answer (score 0):

At first disregarded extensions as they were not showing significant naughty behavior in the Task Manager, however, after disabling all of them i noticed a massive improvement. I'll have to check one by one to find the resource-hungry one.